# cPanel how to access the public_html via filezilla

Tags: cpanel, public-html

I have a big problem with cPanel. I have the access to cPanel but how ever I try to connect to public_html directory it is just impossible. I come so far that I enter the correct server but my uname and pword does not work. So please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I use Mac by the way.

If it helps I can say that I have installed mantis via simple script but I can't access that either via the url.

So I'm totally lost and please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cpanel account, have you looked to see if you have an FTP account configured? Try using ftp.domain.com, cpanel username, cpanel password for FileZilla login credentials. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunetly that didn't help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @dejaninic Do you have a FTP configured for your server?